# Bootstrap template "toggle menu" button does not work in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

> I will use this template in an angular project. [https://startbootstrap.com/previews/simple-sidebar/][1]
>       I have pasted all the template code in the home.component.html; As the code shows. Everything is going well, the css is loaded perfectly and is identical to how the template is in the link.
>       What I need is for the "Toggle menu" button to work.
>       I think it is due to the JS code found at the end of the HTML, however, I don't know how to proceed. Could you please help me.
>         [1]: https://startbootstrap.com/previews/simple-sidebar/

```html
  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar / SIDEBARCOMPONENT-->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <!-- NAVBAR COMPONENT -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVBAR COMPONENT -->
      <!-- HOME COMPONENT -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on
          larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional,
          and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the
          menu when clicked.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- HOME COMPONENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: where is `.toggled` class?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if you mean a css class. Checking I don't see something called that. But you could download the files related to my question in this link: https://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar/

Comment: please check the answer. This was not a JS/TS issue. Its simply that you forgot to link all css files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all the required CSS from the said template. Please find below the completed code.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://startbootstrap.com/assets/style-template.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

  <!-- Sidebar / SIDEBARCOMPONENT-->
  <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <!-- NAVBAR COMPONENT -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR COMPONENT -->
    <!-- HOME COMPONENT -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
      <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
      <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- HOME COMPONENT -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

For Angular - [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5lqemu)

**.html**

```
// use [ngClass] to toggle the class for the div
<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper" [ngClass]="{'toggled': toggled}"></div>

// attach the click 
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle" (click)="onToggle()">Toggle Menu</button>
```

**.ts**

```
toggled = false;

onToggle(){
  this.toggled = !this.toggled;
}
```

Comment: I have pasted all the template code in the home.component.html; as the code of my publication shows (I have edited it). Everything is going well, the css is loaded perfectly and is identical to how the template is in the link.
In addition I have copied and pasted the links (script and Link) of your answer in the index.html that is, the ones I put below, but still, the button does not work.
`<script src="https://code.jquery... ...></script>
<script src="https://stackp....></script>
<link href="https://stackpath......>
<link href="https://blackroc...." />
<link href="https://startbo..../>`

Comment: have update the post and also check the demo link. When you implement, all `.js` and `.css` files needed to be loaded the angular way and not in the component body.

Comment: Really, your example is perfect, it saved my day, Thank you.